# What's the difference between µF and µFD?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, electrical, bom

A datasheet is referencing "CAP SMD0603 CERM 1.0UFD 16V 10% X7R ROHS" which is calling for a UFD. But I have a uF cap C1608X7R1C105K080AC which is "CAP CER 1UF 16V X7R 0603". Should that work fine? Is µF and µFD the same?

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tdk-corporation/C1608X7R1C105K080AC/445-1604-1-ND/634399

Comment: given that 1µF is the same as 1MFD it could be argued that 1µFD is 1aF but that seems unlikey to be a useful unit of measure for a discrete capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that FD was written by somebody attempting to make it sound a bit more like Farad, presumably unaware that F is the recognised abbreviation for Farad.

Answer (score 1):

F and FD are both abbreviations for "Farad", so either capacitor should work.